# Table input in tikzpicture with scatter classes

Tags: pgfplots, floats

I'm getting the error message:

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'a' as a floating point number,
>    sorry. The unreadable part was near 'a'..

Somehow the table cannot be read.
I would like to have an axis with colored points on them. The first part worked until I added the *scatter/classes* and *table* thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=none,
            hide y axis,
            xmin=0,xmax=20,
            ymin=0, ymax=1,
            xtick={0,...,20},
            xticklabels={,,}
            scatter/classes={%
                a={mark=o,draw=blue},
                b={mark=o,draw=red}}]

        \addplot[scatter,only marks,%
            scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
        table[meta=label]{
            x   label
            1   a
            2   a
            3   a
            4   a
            6   a
            13  a
            10  b
            14  b
            17  b
            18  b
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Working example without a plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=none,
            hide y axis,
            xmin=0,xmax=20,
            ymin=0, ymax=1,
            xtick={0,...,20},
            xticklabels={,,},
            scatter/classes={%
                a={mark=o,draw=blue},
                b={mark=o,draw=red}}]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You need to add a `y` column consisting of `0`.

Comment: @Symbol1 unfortunately the same error persists

Comment: And also at the end of `xticklabels={,,}` you missed a comma.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thank you!! That fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Symbol1 fixed this in the comments. Here's the working code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=none,
            hide y axis,
            xmin=0,xmax=20,
            ymin=0, ymax=1,
            xtick={0,...,20},
            xticklabels={,,},
            scatter/classes={%
                a={mark=o,draw=blue},
                b={mark=o,draw=red}}]

        \addplot[scatter,only marks,%
            scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
        table[meta=label]{
            x   y   label
            1   0   a
            2   0   a
            3   0   a
            4   0   a
            6   0   a
            13  0   a
            10  0   b
            14  0   b
            17  0   b
            18  0   b
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```